# Autocomplete of file path does not work after "vim" in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, auto-completion

## Steps to reproduce

```
git clone https://github.com/MichinariNukazawa/vecterion_vge.git
cd vecterion_vge
```

1. input `vim include/` <kbd>tab</kbd>
2. input `vim include/et_co` <kbd>tab</kbd>

## What I expected to see

1. show file list in `include/`
2. autocomplete file path `vim include/et_color_panel.h`

## What I saw instead

Both 1. and 2. do not work.

## Other

Both
`ls include/` <kbd>tab</kbd> and
`ls include/et_co` <kbd>tab</kbd>
do work.

The  input `vim vecterion_vge/include/et_co` <kbd>tab</kbd> on parent directory (home dir) does work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Works well for me in Xubuntu 16.04 in Zsh but does not work in Bash.

Comment: I use in Ubuntu 16.04 in bash.

Comment: Add the output of `complete -p vim`, please.

Comment: output is `complete -F _filedir_xspec vim`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you turned off the completion specifications associated with vim.

```
complete -p vim
```

And check the output:

```
complete -F _filedir_xspec vim
```

If is something like the previous line, run the command:

```
complete -r vim
```

In general, and not directly related to `vim` you can follow these examples, modify for your case:

### First example

You can list all the current completion routines active for your user via `complete -p` or list all the completion included in your system: `ls /etc/bash_completion.d/`

Completion is drived by the file `/etc/bash_completion` and new completion commands may be placed inside the directory `/etc/bash_completion.d`

You need to enable smart completion, editing your /etc/bash.bashrc file. I think you have, because the `cd` Tab completion. Anyway uncomment the following lines, by removing the # in the beginning of the lines:

```
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
# . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
```

As you can see, everything depends on the information inside `bash_completion.d` file.

If you can even extend bash smart completion to your `vim` or `apt` need to edit `/etc/bash_completion` and `/etc/bash_completion.d`

### Other example

If you don't have access to edit files or add archives to `/etc`. You can add local completion, for example for  `wp-cli` you can dowload the completion definition and rename to hide the command:

```
wget https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/raw/master/utils/wp-completion.bash
rename wp-completion.bash .wp-completion.bash
```

Now edit your `.bash_profile` using `nano .bash_profile` or `vim`adding this:

```
source /home/tu_usuario_del_host/.wp-completion.bash
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this solution is not work.

Comment: 1. Because there was something similar to the line you pointed to in /etc/bash.bashrc, I commented out this, but it did not solve it.  
As another method, I copied the line you specified, but it did not solve it.   
  
2. There was no file to be read by `/etc/bash_completion`.  
This is because you pointed out `/etc /bash_completion` and `/etc/bash_completion.d` ?

Comment: I am sorry misunderstood.
`/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` exists.

Comment: I'm away from my Linux computer, this evening I try to check is everything is OK. I didn't use with these commands. I only added completion for `wp-cli` with the following commands:
   
   wget https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/raw/master/utils/wp-completion.bash
   rename wp-completion.bash .wp-completion.bash

Now edit .bash_profile, `nano .bash_profile` adding this:
 
   source /home/tu_usuario_del_host/.wp-completion.bash

Comment: I tryed. Adding `.wp-completion.bash` dose not work.

Comment: Yes, I talk about `wp-completion` as an example. OK restart the completion. Check my edited answer. You need to run: `complete -r vim`

Comment: It solved with `complete -r vim`.  
It is interesting why it was effective.  
Thank you.